# Getting the attribute name that the created object will be given

Tags: python, debugging, introspection, magic-methods

Before I ask this, do note: I want this for debugging purposes. I know that this is going to be some bad black magic, but I want to use it just during debugging so I could identify my objects more easily.

It's like this. I have some object from class `A` that creates a few `B` instances as attributes:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self)
        self.vanilla_b = B()
        self.chocolate_b = B()

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
```

What I want is that in `B.__init__`, it will figure out the `"vanilla_b"` or whatever attribute name it was given, and then put that as the `.name` attribute to this specific `B`.

Then in debugging when I see some `B` object floating around, I could know which one it is.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sys._getframe](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys._getframe) to get the line number where `B()` is called, then you can use [inspect.getsourcelines](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcelines) to get the actual line of code.  From there you can parse the line of code to get the thing to which `B()` is being assigned:

```
import sys
import inspect

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vanilla_b = B()
        self.chocolate_b = B()

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        line_num = sys._getframe().f_back.f_lineno
        lines = inspect.getsourcelines( sys.modules[__name__] )[0]
        line = lines[line_num - 1]
        attr = line.split("=")[0].split(".")[1].strip()
        print "B() is being assigned to", attr

A()
```

If you put the above code into a python script and run it, then it will print

```
B() is being assigned to vanilla_b
B() is being assigned to chocolate_b
```

However, this won't work at the Python command prompt, since `__main__` is a builtin module, and thus the inspect module can't retrieve its source lines.  So you might want to wrap this in a try/catch block or something just in case your code ever gets called from any builtin module.

For the record, this is probably a bad idea, but you say that you're aware that it's not good practice and you're only doing it for debugging, so hopefully you'll be able to use this kind of trickery wisely.

Comment: @cool-RR: I've edited the answer to use the inspect module so that you wouldn't have to type the file name.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for but perhaps you could do something along this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        attrs = ('vanilla_b', 'chocolate_b')

        for attr in attrs:
            instance = B()
            setattr(self, attr, instance)
            instance.name = attr
```

Try wrapping that behavior to some superclass and you might be good to go.

Comment: A bit problematic, I want to have different parameters in the creation of each `B`. If there won't be good enough magic, I might take this method.

Comment: Ok. To work around that you could instantiate attributes as a dict (key=name, value=object).

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over code then it is better to do it simply then rely on some black magic e.g. do

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self)
        self.vanilla_b = B(name="vanilla_b")
        self.chocolate_b = B(name="chocolate_b")
```

otherwise you can use inspect module to go thru locals and self in prev frame and do some vodoo.

Comment: I'm aware of this method, thanks. My whole question is, "how do I do the voodoo?"

Answer (score -1):

Not very magical, but:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self)
        self.vanilla_b = B(self)
        self.chocolate_b = B(self)
```

and:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        for i in dir(a):
            if getattr(a, i) == self:
                pass # store it somewhere now
```

EDIT: Sorry, this won't work. B.**init** is executed before references in A are set.

Comment: No good, the `B` object should not be getting a reference to `A`.